# How do I use a button to link one JS page to another JS page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

At the moment I have this code:

```
<a href='./housing1.html'>
  <button type="button" className="Button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
</a>
```

This easily takes me to an HTML page but when I try to go to a JS page I've created it either just displays the code on the webpage or the page flickers. Is it something to do with the location of the files or do I use something in React to solve this?

Comment: What is a "JS page"?

Comment: Are you using a router to do the switching between different 'pages' which in react are referred to as routes?

Comment: `<a>` elements are forbidden from containing `<button>` elements (and vice versa). Pick one. If you want a link, use a link. If you don't like the way it looks, apply CSS.

Comment: @ArbiasGjoshi how would I use a router with a button?

Comment: Let me write it down on the answer section for you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you are using something like `@reach/router` or `react-router-dom`. Both of them have their component functions such as `Link` that allow you to navigate through your app.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from '@reach/router';

const SampleComponent = () => (
   <div className="someWrapper">
     <Link to='/your-path'>  
      <button type="button" className="Button btn btn-dark btn-lg btn-block">
          Submit
      </button>
     </Link>
     <h1>Other code would enter here</h1>
   </div>
)

export default SampleComponent;
```

Do know that in order for this to work **you also need to set up your router page** to be able to navigate. Read the docs of the respective packages because they are quite straightforward and easy to integrate.

P.S - React doesn't allow you to use `class` property because that is a reserved keyword in ECMAScript. So to assign any classes as in the case you have done with your buttons put everything inside `className`

Also please pay attention to the comment above to not use button's inside links but rather style your anchor tags as buttons and thus achieving the desired logic.